# Replace constructor variables of type A with type B, for classes that extend C

Tags: java, intellij-idea, structural-search

I have about 100 classses that look like this.

```
public class MyClass extends MyBaseClass {
    public MyClass(OldType variable, int var2, OldType v3) {
        //stuff
```

Now i want to replace all *constructor variables* of type *OldType* in classes that extend *MyBaseClass* with the same variable name, but of type *NewType*.
So it will look like this:

```
public class MyClass extends MyBaseClass {
    public MyClass(NewType variable, int var2, NewType v3) {
        //stuff
```

The amount and names of the variables will vary.

I have already gotten IDEA to find all classes that extend `MyBaseClass` using Structural replace, but were do i go from there?

Comment: If you do not need OldType anymore, if you rename NewType to OldType and then you are done.

Comment: sadly i do, and its used quite a few other places

Comment: Have you tried Refractor->Type Migration?

Comment: Wont work, as i only need to replace OldClass with NewClass in the aforementioned constructors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is using two search steps. Step one: find the parameters of the constructors of classes extending `MyBaseClass`.

```
class $A$ extends $B$ {
    $A$($T$ $p$);
}
```

Variables
B - Text/regexp: `MyBaseClass`, enable *Apply constraint within type hierarchy*
p - Enable *This variable is the target of the search*, Occurrences count: `1, unlimited`

Step two: Replace variables of the right type in scope `Previous Search Results`.

```
OldType $a$
```

Replacement template:

```
NewType $a$
```

Comment: you sir, are a genious